# Intellisense Not Recognizing Data Type

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2019

I am new to both C# and Unity. Very new.

I created a new C# script and I'm trying to add the following line:

```
public Vector3 direction = Vector3.up
```

When I go to type in Vector3, my only option that has anything with Vector in it is "BitVector32".

I am using a 3D object in Unity.

What do I need to do?

**Edit:** I am using the following:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
```

**Edit:**

1. I have confirmed Visual Tools for Unity is installed.
2. I am using UnityEngine at the top.
3. Below is the code I am using. All I am trying to figure out is why

intellisense does not recognize Vector3 sense it is a data type. It recognizes "BitVector32" but not "Vector3" though, when I run this code, everything works fine.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using UnityEngine;

public class Mover : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Vector3 is unique to UnityEngine

    public Vector3 direction = Vector3.up;

    float speed = 0.1f;

    void Update()
    {
        var movement = direction * speed;

        this.transform.Translate(movement);
    }
}
```

Comment: So when you add this line of code. Unity is giving out an Error? If yes could you please add an Image of that Error.

Comment: And please attach a whole script code

Comment: In case you are using VisualStudio: Do you have `Visual Studio Tools For Unity` installed?

Comment: There is no error, I have attached my code, all I want to know is why intellisense is not recognizing Vector3, despite the fact that the whole code runs. How can I made intellisense recognize it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be a little late to this, but I've had the same problem. What worked for me was to go in Unity, go to the top left and select Edit->Preferences and open the External Tools tab. In there the first option should be External Script Editor. Make sure you've selected Microsoft Visual Studio 20xx. Intellisense should get a hold of Unity specific objects and data types and be able to recognise things like Vector3.

Answer (score 2):

I would check if you have included `using UnityEngine;`

Comment: That line is what I'm trying to add. It comes from a book I am reading. When I type "Vector" into Visual studio, only "BitVector32" comes up, why doesn't Vector3 come up? That's my problem.

Comment: Edited my original post for more context.

Answer (score 1):

Does your IDE understand other keywords such as Input or Application? if it does not recognize those, try to install Unity Games Development Tools from visual studio installer.
also, [Jetbrains Rider](https://www.jetbrains.com/rider/) is another IDE that is very useful for Unity developers.